# How to find Eigen's AutoDiffScalar second derivative?

Tags: eigen, autodiff

I'm diving into AutoDiff module of Eigen-3.3.7. Consider this simple example of finding derivatives of x<sup>2</sup>.

```cpp
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Core>
#include <eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/AutoDiff>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  Eigen::AutoDiffScalar<Eigen::Vector2d> x(8.0, Eigen::Vector2d(1,0)), y;

  y = x*x;

  std::cout << "x = " << x << "\n"
            << "y = " << y << "\n"
            << "y' = " << y.derivatives()[0] << "\n"
            << "y'' = " << y.derivatives()[1] << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Output for the second derivative is 0 instead of 2. How to correctly find it?

Comment: It is not possible with the current implementation, and I'm not sure how much effort this would be. You may instead try [ADOL-C](https://projects.coin-or.org/ADOL-C), which according to their homepage supports higher-order derivatives (I did not try this). There is also an [Eigen-module for that](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/unsupported/group__AdolcForward__Module.html).

Comment: Even more possible alternatives: http://www.autodiff.org/?module=Tools&language=C%2FC%2B%2B

Answer (score 0):

Here is a semi-official example I've found:

1. Function definition (should output a scalar)

```
    template <typename T>
    T my_matrixfun(
        Eigen::Matrix<T,Eigen::Dynamic,1> const &a,
        Eigen::Matrix<T,Eigen::Dynamic,1> const &b)
    {
        Eigen::Matrix<T,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::Dynamic> m(a.size(),a.size());
        m.setZero();
        m.diagonal() = a;
        return (b.transpose() * m * b)(0,0);
    }
```

2. Extracting gradient and hessian:

   ```
    typedef Eigen::Matrix<double,Eigen::Dynamic,1> inner_derivative_type;
    typedef Eigen::AutoDiffScalar<inner_derivative_type> inner_active_scalar;
    typedef Eigen::Matrix<inner_active_scalar,Eigen::Dynamic,1>    outer_derivative_type;
    typedef Eigen::AutoDiffScalar<outer_derivative_type> outer_active_scalar;
    typedef Eigen::Matrix<outer_active_scalar,Eigen::Dynamic,1> AVector;
    AVector Aa(a.size()),Ab(b.size());

    // copy value from non-active example
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)Aa(i).value().value() = a(i);
    for(int i=0;i<b.size();i++)Ab(i).value().value() = b(i);
    // initialize derivative vectors
    const int derivative_num = a.size() + b.size();
    int derivative_idx = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<Aa.size();i++){
        init_twice_active_var(Aa(i),derivative_num,derivative_idx);
        derivative_idx++;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<Ab.size();i++){
        init_twice_active_var(Ab(i),derivative_num,derivative_idx);
        derivative_idx++;
    }

    outer_active_scalar Ac = my_matrixfun(Aa,Ab);
    std::cout << "Result: " << Ac.value().value() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Gradient: " <<
                 Ac.value().derivatives().transpose() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Hessian" << std::endl;
    Eigen::MatrixXd hessian(Ac.derivatives().size(),Ac.derivatives().size());
    for(int idx=0;idx<Ac.derivatives().size();idx++){
        hessian.middleRows(idx,1) =
                Ac.derivatives()(idx).derivatives().transpose();
    }
    std::cout << hessian << std::endl;
   ```